# Unable to pass parameters with periods in Oracle APEX / REST

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

Using Oracle APEX 5.0.4, with Oracle 12c.  I am trying to write a REST service in Oracle APEX.  I have a SQL statement...

```
select * from <my_table> where company_name = 'GOOGLE INC.'
```

When run from a straight SQL prompt, this runs and returns data.  I have tried to implement this in a REST service, specifically using a URI template.  I am using a bind variable, so my query now looks like.

```
select * from <my_table> where company_name = :ACCT_NAME;
```

Both the space and the period in my company name are causing me problems, returning no rows.  If my BIND VARIABLE is a single word, then no problems.  I found UTL_URL.UNESCAPE, and have tried to use that. This seems to solve the problem of having a space, but does not fix issue when the company name contains a period.

I rewrote my SQL Statement to

```
select * from <my_table> where company_name = UTL_URL.UNESCAPE(:ACCT_NAME);
```

The query will work if the BIND VARIABLE (aka company name) is multiple words, but NOT containing a period.  For example, I can look up 'GOOGLE INC' by setting my bind variable = 'GOOGLE%20INC' .  I need to be able to look up 'GOOGLE INC.' [notice the period at the end of INC]  so I set my bind variable = 'GOOGLE%20INC%2E' and I consistently get 'BAD REQUEST'. It appears that the URI template is not valid.

If I pass this in via a straight SQL statement (aka OUTSIDE of the REST service), my data is found...

```
select * from <my_table> where company_name = UTL_URL.UNESCAPE('GOOGLE%20INC%2E');
```

There is something unique about the PERIOD character... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try escaping the period like this: 'GOOGLE INC\.'

Comment: I had not, but upon trying, it did not solve the issue.  The ONLY way I have been able to get this to work is to substitute a ~ for a period on the client, and then on the server ...

where ( ACCOUNT_NAME =  UTL_URL.UNESCAPE(REPLACE(:ACCT_NAME, '~', '.')))